# javascript serialization - a short library

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I have to save in a cookie a small amount of data.

Would be wonderful if javascript (natively) provide a way to serialize/deserialize an array (or an object).

To be honest, I have tried to write my own piece of code, it is based on the idea that we could serialize an array recursively converting it in a key/value querystring and viceversa.

Well, this is the code:

```
var lib = {
    serialize : function(_a) {
        var s = '', enc = encodeURIComponent;
        for (var k in _a) {
            if (s) s += '&';
            s += enc(k) + '=' + ((typeof _a[k] == 'object') ? '?'+enc(lib.serialize(_a[k])) : enc(_a[k]));
        }
        return s;
    },
    deserialize : function(_s) {
        var a = [], dec = decodeURIComponent;
        var list = _s.split('&');
        for (var c in list) {
            var kv = list[c].split('=');
            var v = kv[1].split('?'); 
            kv[1] = (v.length > 1) ? lib.deserialize(dec(v[1])) : dec(kv[1]);
            a[dec(kv[0])] = kv[1];
        }
        return a;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7wT8/

Although it seems to works quite fine, could someone suggest me something of better and shorter?
A piece of code or a library, something of little and easy to implement Javascript array serialize/deserialize ?

Comment: Are you being charged for every keystroke? All this shorthand is impossible to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best approach is to [use JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON).

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` can encode and decode the values.
JSON is a standard format nowadays, so it is clearer to other developers what's happening.

The only limitation is that IE 7 and below do not support `JSON` functions natively and require a library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need something that is little and portable.

Comment: Thanks, I see that in the link you suggested, there is a really short and portable implementation of `JSON` format, just in case it is not natively available. Maybe this is what I was looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON#Browser_compatibility